# How do I put a variable in style canvas?

Tags: html, variables, canvas, background-color

Is it possible put a global variable in "background-color:", then set that variable with a color?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<script>

var colore = #ff0000;

</script>

<canvas id="nota1" class="Nota"
width="300" height="200"
style="border:3px solid black; background-color:VARIABLE_HERE;">
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with JavaScript

```js
var color = 'black'; // sample only

document.getElementById("nota1").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

```html
<canvas id="nota1" class="Nota" width="300" height="200" style="border:3px solid black;"></canvas>
```

You can do it also with CSS only

```
<canvas id="nota1" class="Nota" width="300" height="200"></canvas>

#nota1 {
    background-color: black; /* sample */
    border: 1px solid black; /* sample */
}
```